# NPIV support on RHEL Hypervisor (KVM)

Tags: linux, hypervisor

We are planning to setup RHEL KVM hypervisor on a Physical machine and then create multiple Linux VMs on that hypervisor.

In order to directly map/present Storage LUNs to these VMs, we are planning to use NPIV technology of KVM.

I want to clarify few things:

1. Is KVM NPIV technology same as NPIV technology of Windows 2012 Server Hypervisor where once NPIV environment is set correctly, Storage LUNs can be directly mapped to VM using virtual WWN?
2. What are the supported guest VM OS type which are supported for NPIV like RHEL, SUSE etc.
3. Any particular Network switch types which supports KVM NPIV technology.

It will be great if somebody knows the answer of these questions and share them.

Thanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  NPIV is an ANSI Standard, so yes it is the same idea as 2012 Hyper-V Uses.

2)  I'm looking for this info as well, will update if I get it.  http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_virtualization/rhel_6_virtualization_chap-Para-virtualized_Windows_Drivers_Guide-N_Port_ID_Virtualization_NPIV.html seems to indicate it's agnostic to the guest operating system, but I have a couple contacts I'm asking for details from.

3)  Brocade and Cisco FC switches both support.